# How to prevent custom fields from being cleared during a bulk edit?

Tags: custom-field, admin, bulk

In my function for saving custom field values I add a few checks to prevent the values from being cleared during an autosave or a quick edit.

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_my_post');
function save_my_post($post_id)
{
    // Stop WP from clearing custom fields on autosave,
    // and also during ajax requests (e.g. quick edit).
    if ((defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) || (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX))
        return;

    // Clean, validate and save custom fields
    $myfield = ( ! isset($_POST['myfield'])) ? '' : strval($_POST['myfield']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'myfield', $myfield);
}
```

It appears, though, that the custom fields are still cleared in the case of a bulk edit. The `DOING_AUTOSAVE` and `DOING_AJAX` checks don't apply to bulk edits.

I realize that you could simply not call [`update_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) if the applicable `$_POST` variables are not set. That wouldn't work in the case of checkboxes, though.

Ideally, a simple check to determine whether we're in a bulk edit or not would do the job. Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check for a bulk edit by looking at the `bulk_edit` variable in `$_GET` or `$_POST`. Bulk edits are typically GET requests as far as I investigated them.

Note that `$_REQUEST` takes both GET and POST data into account. In `wp-admin/edit.php` they also do an `isset()` check for `$_REQUEST['bulk_edit']`.

```
function save_my_post($post_id)
{
    // Do nothing during a bulk edit
    if (isset($_REQUEST['bulk_edit']))
        return;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Helped me in a similar problem.