# Custom fields and auto save

Tags: custom-field, automatic-updates, autosave

I have the issue of data in custom fields dissapearing after auto save, but no answer here helped me ([Custom field being erased after autosave](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37967/custom-field-being-erased-after-autosave)).

I have this custom field:

```
 add_action('save_post', 'save_intro');
function admin_init(){
        add_meta_box("customField1", "Intro", "fieldIntro", "post", "normal", "high");

function fieldIntro(){
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $intro = $custom["intro"][0];
        wp_editor( $intro, 'intro', $settings = array('textarea_rows'=>10) ); 
    }   
    function save_intro(){ //preserve the data in the admin section
        global $post;
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "intro", $_POST["intro"]);
    }
```

I tried the following solutions (inserted them after my functions above):

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_my_post');
function save_my_post($post_id)
{
    // Stop WP from clearing custom fields on autosave,
    // and also during ajax requests (e.g. quick edit) and bulk edits.
    if ((defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) || (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) || isset($_REQUEST['bulk_edit']))
        return;

    // Clean, validate and save custom fields
}
```

this one too:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');
function save_details(){
   if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

   global $post;
   update_post_meta($post->ID, "intro", $_POST["intro"]);

}
```

But still, if I wait for an autosave and then click on the autosave  and get to that revision the custom fields data is lost.

Maybe I'm not replicating the issue in a pertinent way?

Thanks!

Comment: The answers in the question linked to (and your attempts to fix the problem) look correct. Do you have any plugins installed that might interfere? Have you tested this with a bundled theme -- Twenty-something?

Comment: @s_ha_dum no plugins, but I'm gonna test with the base theme. Is it correct to expect that this solution will save the data in autosave revisions? So when switching to an autosaved revision the custom fields become blank, or is it another way to replicate it?

Comment: It is not working even with the base theme so I'm assuming the issue is with how I replicate the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check to see whether the `$_POST` data contains your custom field information before saving it:

```
  if (!empty($_POST["intro"])) {
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "intro", $_POST["intro"]);
  }
```

Also, Wordpress will pass the post ID and post object into your callback if you ask it too.

```
function save_intro($ID, $post){ //preserve the data in the admin section
 // ...
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_intro',10,2);
```

You don't need that `global $post` at all.

Comment: If you have a custom field titled `custom_title` will this solution cause the field to save on scheduled? Im running in to the same issue but only on scheduled posts. On save Im logging out the fields but not getting the custom field. So Im trying to get auto save to store the field...